# How should we abbreviate the tag for "Affordable Space Adventures"?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214050/how-many-levels-are-there-in-affordable-space-adventures) question was asked, but with the inappropriate tag. I tried to add the tag [affordable-space-adventures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affordable-space-adventures), but that is 27 characters long. I'm not sure how to abbreviate the gamename (or remove the dashes, but then it becomes unreadable), so that is fits into the tag.

Comment: cheap-space-trips?

Comment: That would do the trick. However, the findability and usability is not very high, I suppose :P

Comment: [tag:affordable-space-adv] maybe?

Comment: @Ktash I think something like that will work. If someone want to ask a question about it, they first type in 'afford-'. If that tag pops-up, it will be used

Comment: Only real way I can think about shortening it and still getting that. I searched around but didn't see any abbreviations for it in use on any other pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I edited the question, and took @Ktash's suggestion. The new tag is now [affordable-space-adv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affordable-space-adv). When one enters the first few characters of the gamename, then this tag will pop-up.

Comment: With cases like this, please feel free to edit the tag wiki blurb for the game with the proper name so it shows up on hover. It helps to disambiguate the game when we have cases where the title won't fit within the tag limit.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Now that the tag length was [increased to 35 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've went ahead and retagged both questions with the full title.

The tag name is now [affordable-space-adventures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affordable-space-adventures).